# Max value of array in MIPs assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

So I am currently learning MIPs assembly for the first time, and one of my tasks is to find the maximum signed value in a given array using only 'beq' and 'slt' conditional commands.
However, when I run the program, the register that holds MAX value always seems to become zero, when it should be `-4`.
Here is the given array: `{-32, -8, -4, -16, -128, -64}`
And here is my code. The code that does the MAX value runs from L2 to L4. Ignore L1 and L5 as it was provided, and all I did was change the labels to them.

```
# local variable    register
#   int *p      $s0            can ignore this
#   int *end    $s1            Last element in array
#   int sum     $s2            can ignore this
#   int max     $s3            name of MAX register!
#   int *q      $s4            pointer to abc
#   abc                        the name of the array


main:
    la  $s0, abc                # p = abc
    addi $s1, $s0, 24            # end = p + 6
    add $s2, $zero, $zero     # sum = 0 
L1:
    beq $s0, $s1, L2             # if (p == end) goto L2
    lw  $t9, ($s0)           # $t9 = *p
    add $s2, $s2, $t9         # sum += $t9
    addi $s0, $s0, 4             # p++
    j   L1
L2:     
    la  $s4, abc                #q = abc. This is where my portion of the code starts
    lw  $t1, ($s4)           #putting p[1] into t1
    add $s3, $zero, $t1       #setting p[1] as max by default
    j   L3  

L3:
    beq     $s4, $s1, L5        #if p goes to end, goto L5
    addi    $s4, $s4, 4     #advancing p[i]
    lw  $t8, ($s4)          #putting p[i] into t8
    add $s5, $zero, $t8
    slt $t0, $s3, $t8       #if t1 < t8, t0 becomes one
    bne $t0, $zero, L4     #if if t0 = zer0, or in other words t1 < t8, goto L4
    j   L3
L4:
    add $s3, $zero, $s5     #storing t8/s5 into max
    j   L3

L5:
    add $v0, $zero, $zero   # return value from main = 0
    jr  $ra
```

When I run my code step by step, the FINAL JUMP FROM L4 to L3 seems to set the register $s3 to zero. but more confusingly, it is holding "-64" right before then. 
So basically what I am asking is, what error in my code keeps resetting $s3 to zero? Why did $s3 have "-64" when it is cleary incorrect?

Comment: Your array is declared as an array of words, right?  `abc: .word -32, -8, -4, -16, -128, -64` in the .data section?  You should include that as part of your [mcve].  (Otherwise nice job with the MCVE and actually explaining what you see when single-stepping.)  I haven't spotted the problem yet, but `#putting p[1] into t1` is wrong: you're loading `q[0]`, the first element, not `q[1]` = `4($s1)`.  Also, you don't need `j L3` there; execution falls through to the next instruction on its own.  Your `bne` over a `j L3` at the bottom of the L3 loop is also over-complicated, just `beq L3`.

Comment: Also, normally a function should not modify `$s` registers without saving/restoring them (they're call-preserved); use `$t0..9` for internal locals; they're call-clobbered in the standard calling convention.  And BTW, you can reuse the same register for a pointer for the 2nd loop over the array.  Or better, calculate max in the same loop that sums the array instead of looping twice.  And yes, if you can assume the array is non-empty, starting with max = first element is good.

Comment: I think you have an off-by-one.  Your end pointer is one-past-the-end of the array, like C++ .begin / .end iterators.  But you increment and use it *after* checking.  The normal way would be to increment and conditional branch at the bottom of your loops, and fall-through to leave the loop.  Your sum loop apparently isn't affected because the words after the array are zero, and sum += 0 doesn't affect it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the insight. Yes I declared the array as an array of words. could the error stem from the pointer going out of bounds? but the program seems to go all the way to the end without crashing. Just the value of MAX is incorrect.

Comment: Memory protection usually works on page boundaries, and MARS probably simulates it that way.  You can usually load some garbage or zeroes from past the end of an array, so not CPU faults/exceptions is not evidence of correctness.  Look at the order of check / load / increment in L1, vs. your check / increment / load in L3.  Max is fine (I think), you're just using it wrong.